# Example of a lattice which is distributive but not bounded

Tags: lattice-orders

Distributive lattices may or may not be bounded.
Can someone give an example of a distributive lattice which is not bounded?

Comment: How about the positive integers, with the partial order of divisibility? GCD distributes over LCM, and vice versa. The least element is $1$, because $1\mid n$ for any $n$; but there is no greatest element. The greatest element would be $0$, because $n\mid0$ for any $n$ (that is, there exists $x$ such that $n\cdot x=0$), but $0$ is not a positive integer.

Comment: Or consider the real numbers, with the usual ordering. $\max$ distributes over $\min$. There is no greatest real number.

Comment: Did you see [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice#Examples)? You are expected to search for answers before asking a question here. See [how to ask a good question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).